# Clever way to build a extension method that ordenate my IQueryable<T>?

Tags: c#, optimization, linq, entity-framework, extension-methods

I want to create a ExtensionMethod to ordenate my linq query, called `Ordenar`. I'll sort it depending what columns is in `sortColumns` ListDictionary.

I tried some ways, but the best way I arquieve was this :

```
static class ClienteBusinessExtensions
    {
        public static IQueryable<Model.View_Clientes> Ordernar(this IQueryable<Model.View_Clientes> viewClientes, ListDictionary sortColumns)
        {
            foreach (System.Collections.DictionaryEntry item in sortColumns)
            {
                if (item.Value.ToString()=="ASC")
                {
                    switch (item.Key.ToString())
                    {
                        case "ClienteID":
                            viewClientes = viewClientes.OrderBy(v => v.ClienteID);
                            break;
                        case "Nome":
                            viewClientes = viewClientes.OrderBy(v => v.Nome);
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else //item.Value.ToString() will be DESC
                {
                    switch (item.Key.ToString())
                    {
                        case "ClienteID":
                            viewClientes = viewClientes.OrderByDescending(v => v.ClienteID);
                            break;
                        case "Nome":
                            viewClientes = viewClientes.OrderByDescending(v => v.Nome);
                            break;
                        case "CpfCnpj":
                            viewClientes = viewClientes.OrderByDescending(v => v.CpfCnpj);
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }

            }
            return viewClientes;
        }
```

It is used like this :

```
var clientesVip = (from vips in db.View_Clientes
                               .Ordernar(sortColumns)
                           select vips);
```

Are there a clever way to do it? I don't want to use switch statement. I want to sort any field of View_Clientes. It is used in a Asp.NET gridView, when user sort a column.

And View_Clientes entity is :

```
public partial class View_Clientes
{
    public System.Guid ClienteID { get; set; }
    public string Codcfo { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string CpfCnpj { get; set; }
    public string CLI_Origem { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely could use DynamicLinq to solve this problem.  See Scott Guthries blog post about it at:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx